# 'Undoing' a square root transformation for linear regression

Tags: regression

I have a time series that I'd like to perform regression on. It's not linear, or homoscedastic.

After applying a square root transformation to the dependent variable, which made the graph linear.

I applied the sklearn LinearRegression model, and checked the distribution of the residuals, which are normally distributed. Additionally, I checked for homoscedascity, and found that to be the case.

My question is, is it valid for me to just square the values of the regression line, and plot it against the graph of my original values to undo the transformation? Can I do the same with standard error lines?

(Edit: typos)

Comment: If your estimate for the square root is say $\widehat{\sqrt{y_i}}=20$ then you can square this to give an estimate for the value of $\hat y_i =400$, but you need to realise that this transformation makes this estimate biased and the uncertainty asymmetric (so a range for the square root of $10-30$ when squared becomes $100-900$ and $400$ is not in the middle of that)

Comment: @Henry you could probably make the comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From comment:*

If your estimate for the square root is say $\widehat{\sqrt{y_i}}=20$ then you can square this to give an estimate for the value of $\hat y_i=400$,

but you need to realise that this transformation makes this estimate biased and the uncertainty asymmetric (so a range for the square root of $10−30$ when squared becomes $100−900$, and $400$ is not in the middle of that)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!

Is there a way to account for, and offset, the bias, or rather do you just have to be aware that it's there?

Comment: @AGriffen You have to be aware that it is there.  Similar things would happen with taking logarithms or other non-linear transformations

Comment: If the transformation makes the distribution symmetric, then the reverse-transformed values estimate the median of the distribution on the original scale.  If you want to estimate the mean without assuming a distribution you can use the smearing estimator.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Is that the distribution of the residuals, sorry?

Comment: Correct; distribution of residuals on the transformed scale.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to account for the bias, such as [Duan's smearing estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Duan%27s+smearing+estimator+score%3A1).